# Predicting next bit in a nonrandom serie

Tags: probability, cryptography, coding-theory

I have a nonrandom sequence of bits - I'm able to tell that the sequence is nonrandom because I have performed on it the runs test, moreover the sequence presents autocorrelation at lag 1 equal to 0.4 (right before the cutoff) whereas the partial auto correlation function has a sinusoidal behaviour... any suggestion on how to exploit those regularities, without assuming that the sequence follows a binomial distribution?

Moreover, are there any coding theory papers that try to attack the problem assuming that the next bit can be decoded from the previous $n$ knowing these regularity properties?

Comment: Several issues. You seem to assume that "random sequence bits" means "independent bits"  - but that's not the usual definition of a random sequence. Correlation is, in general, allowed.
Further,  what "right before the cutoff" means? Also, I don't understand "without assuming that sequence follows a binomial distribution" ? Are we speaking of a sequence of bits (0/1)  or what? Why would someone assume a binomial distribution? (of what?) I cannot make sense of this.

Comment: I was assuming that you can model a sequence of zeros and ones with a binomial distribution, because 0=failure, 1=success... if the runs test tells me that the sequence is somewhat non random, my best guess is that it can be modeled as a biased coin... with "right before the cutoff" I mean that there's only autocorrelation at lag one and then vanishes